# Hashmap replace the same key "m" as "mL" , is there anyway to fix it?

Tags: java, replace, hashmap

I have this mathematical expression:

```
String exp = "k+(mP/P+mL/L)";
```

Then i create a new HashMap and put exactly the same params as the above expression :

```
Map<String, Integer> mp = new HashMap<>();
mp.put("k", 1);
mp.put("mP", 2);
mp.put("P", 3);
mp.put("mL", 4);
mp.put("L", 5);
```

Finally i continue doing a litteration all of the entry-set by replace the parameter of my expression to values  and after that i print my result:

```
for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> e: mp.entrySet()){

    exp = exp.replace(e.getKey(),e.getValue().toString());
}
System.out.println(exp);
```

*the result of the above is : "1+(m3/3 +m5/5)"*

*but i want this instead : "1+(2/3+4/5)"

Is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expression replaceAll with word-boundary `\b`.

```
exp = exp.replaceAll("\\b" + e.getKey() + "\\b", e.getValue().toString());
```

You could also look into the **scripting API** or the java **REPL**.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by HashMap not keeping insert order. Using LinkedHashMap, which keeps insertion order will solve the problem.

```
Map<String, Integer> mp = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

[String.replace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) replaces all occurrence of the substring, so if `P` gets replaced before `mP`, it can lead to problems like the one you described. To avoid that, you can build the expression with placeholders, which don't have common letters. Like this for example:

```
String exp = "a+(b/c+d/e)";
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why would insertion order matter in this case?

Comment: @hfontanez Because the operation is order-sensitive. Replacing all instances of "L" and then "mL" is very different compared to replacing all instances of "mL" and then "L".

Comment: @BambooleanLogic thanks for the explanation. The point was for the OP to answer it. Answers with no explanation are often not good answers. Fortunately, the OP edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also sort the keys by their length:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String exp = "k+(mP/P+mL/L)";

    Map<String, Integer> mp = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    mp.put("mP", 2);
    mp.put("mL", 4);
    mp.put("k", 1);
    mp.put("P", 3);
    mp.put("L", 5);

    String[] keys = new String[mp.keySet().size()];

    int i = 0;
    for (String k : mp.keySet()) {
        keys[i] = k;
        i++;
    }

    /* Sort array by string length (longest string at the beginning) */
    Arrays.sort(keys, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(b.length(), a.length()));

    for (String k : keys) {
        exp = exp.replace(k, mp.get(k).toString());
    }
    System.out.println(exp); // 1+(2/3+4/5)
}
```